# What shape does my Input layer need to be? I keep getting ValueError: Layer "model" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, recommendation-engine

This is taking the code from [this project](https://github.com/khanhnamle1994/movielens/blob/master/Deep_Learning_Model.ipynb) and converting to the Keras functional API. I [un-subclassed the model from here](https://github.com/khanhnamle1994/movielens/blob/master/CFModel.py) and re-define it starting at `inputs`.

The snag I'm running into is I get the following error when I try to fit the model.

```
ValueError: Layer "model" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: 
[<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None,) dtype=int64>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None,) dtype=int64>]
```

So I must have the shape of the initial tensor wrong- but I'm unsure how to proceed as I've tried a few different ways and nothing seems to make sense.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
# Import CF Model Architecture
from CFModel import CFModel

RNG_SEED = 42

# Reading ratings file
ratings = pd.read_csv('data/ratings.csv', sep='\t', encoding='latin-1', 
                      usecols=['user_id', 'movie_id', 'user_emb_id', 'movie_emb_id', 'rating'])
max_userid = ratings['user_id'].drop_duplicates().max()
max_movieid = ratings['movie_id'].drop_duplicates().max()

# Reading ratings file
users = pd.read_csv('data/users.csv', sep='\t', encoding='latin-1', 
                    usecols=['user_id', 'gender', 'zipcode', 'age_desc', 'occ_desc'])

# Reading ratings file
movies = pd.read_csv('data/movies.csv', sep='\t', encoding='latin-1', 
                     usecols=['movie_id', 'title', 'genres'])

# Create training set
shuffled_ratings = ratings.sample(frac=1., random_state=RNG_SEED)

# Shuffling users
Users = shuffled_ratings['user_emb_id'].values
print( 'Users:', Users, ', shape =', Users.shape)
# Users: [5411 5439  367 ...  853 4032  785] , shape = (1000209,)

# Shuffling movies
Movies = shuffled_ratings['movie_emb_id'].values
print( 'Movies:', Movies, ', shape =', Movies.shape)
# Movies: [2682  903 3716 ... 3101 3478 1390] , shape = (1000209,)

# Shuffling ratings
Ratings = shuffled_ratings['rating'].values
print( 'Ratings:', Ratings, ', shape =', Ratings.shape)
# Ratings: [2 5 4 ... 3 5 4] , shape = (1000209,)

K_FACTORS = 100 # The number of dimensional embeddings for movies and users
TEST_USER = 2000 # A random test user (user_id = 2000)
# Define model

inputs = layers.Input(shape=(1000209, 100)) # What should this input be? 

embeddingUsers = layers.Embedding(max_userid, K_FACTORS, input_length=1)
usersEmbedded = embeddingUsers(inputs)

embeddingMovies = layers.Embedding(max_movieid, K_FACTORS, input_length=1)
moviesEmbedded = embeddingMovies(inputs)

inputs = layers.Dot(axes=1)([usersEmbedded, moviesEmbedded])

outputs = layers.Dense(5, activation='relu')(inputs)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
keras.utils.plot_model(model, "my_first_model_with_shape_info.png", show_shapes=True)

print(model.summary())
#  Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
# =================================================================
#  input_2 (InputLayer)        [(None, 100, 100, 100, 1  0
#                              00)]

#  dense (Dense)               (None, 100, 100, 100, 5)  505

# =================================================================
# Total params: 505
# Trainable params: 505
# Non-trainable params: 0
# _________________________________________________________________

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="mse")

history = model.fit(
    [Users, Movies],
    Ratings,
    epochs=10,
    batch_size=32,
    validation_split=0.2,
) 

# ValueError: Layer "model" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: 
# [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None,) dtype=int64>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None,) dtype=int64>]
```

Comment: Based on the argument provided by you in the model the shape of the array should be (1000209, 100). However, instead of providing the single 2d array, you are providing a tuple in fit command. This is the cause of the error.

Comment: I retried as you suggested updating the input to a list, and updated the post. It's still the same error resulting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing up a few things. The `CFModel`, which you referenced and are trying to convert into a `Model` with the functional API, consists of two `Sequential` sub-models. If you want to pass two inputs to your model, it should have two `Input` layers:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

max_userid = 5000
max_movieid = 5000
K_FACTORS = 100
user_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
movie_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))

embedding_users = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(max_userid, K_FACTORS, input_length=1)
users_embedded = embedding_users(user_input)

embedding_movies = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(max_movieid, K_FACTORS, input_length=1)
movies_embedded = embedding_movies(movie_input)

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Dot(axes=1)([users_embedded, movies_embedded])
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='relu')(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[user_input, movie_input], outputs=outputs)

tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, "my_first_model_with_shape_info.png", show_shapes=True)

print(model.summary())

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="mse")

history = model.fit(
    [Users, Movies],
    Ratings,
    epochs=10,
    batch_size=32,
    validation_split=0.2,
)
```

```
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_4 (InputLayer)           [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_5 (InputLayer)           [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 embedding_2 (Embedding)        (None, 1, 100)       500000      ['input_4[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 embedding_3 (Embedding)        (None, 1, 100)       500000      ['input_5[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 dot_1 (Dot)                    (None, 100, 100)     0           ['embedding_2[0][0]',            
                                                                  'embedding_3[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 dense_1 (Dense)                (None, 100, 5)       505         ['dot_1[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,000,505
Trainable params: 1,000,505
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```

[image]

Since both `Users` and `Movies` have the shape `(1000209,)`, your input shape for both `Input` layers is `shape=(1,)`. This means that each sample consists of an ID that is mapped to a 100-dimensional vector using the  `Embedding` layers. Oh, and just in case it's not intentional, the `CFModel` does not use a `Dense` layer after calculating the dot product.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. It should be noted that I also had to add in reshaping layers `usersReshaped = layers.Reshape((K_FACTORS,))(usersEmbedded)` and `moviesReshaped = layers.Reshape((K_FACTORS,))(moviesEmbedded)`.

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot the reshape layer. Glad it helped